# To create a tab widget with custom design

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I would like to create a android application with the following page.[image]

I would like to create a tab UI as it is in the image. Can anyone please help me how I can replicate the same design using the tab widget and tab host.

In Short I would like to design the BUY and SELL tabs as same as it is in the Image.

Comment: Have you managed to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Create a fragment_buy and another fragment_sell in your layout folder. Then create a Java class for each of them. Both  of these fragments should run on top of your main activity

Comment: I would like to know How I can customize UI of the tabs to make it exactly as it is in the screen

Comment: Add relative layouts on each of your fragments then drag and drop your dropdown menu and your search bar on your fragment_sell.